Servicenow scripted rest api returning 301/redirect
I have made scripted rest api and now being accessed by other applications.
when I access this same exact url through postman with same Auth information, header and body that will return 200(normal response body).
However, when it was accessed from Other application
server: snow_adc
Date:---
Content-Type:text/html
Content-Length:1XX
Connection:keep-alive
Location:https://www.servicenow.com
responseBody:
301 Moved Permanently301 Moved 
 Permanentlysnow_adc
Have already checked IP Address Access Controls but it does not seem like the reason.
Could somebody tell me, what is making this 301 response ?
